# Calculate age in months and years OR format seconds as years and months?

Tags: mysql

I need to find out the age of a person at a certain point in time. I've got both the DOB and this 'point in time' as unix timestamps.

I could subtract them to get their age in seconds at that time, but... I don't see any [MySQL functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to format it into years and months.

How can I do that?

Specifically, the format I want is `5y 6m`.

Comment: You won't be able to do this sort of complicated parsing through MySQL. You'll need to use a script, in a language such as PHP or Python.

Comment: @Patrick: Fairly certain I *can*. MySQL is pretty powerful. Whether or not it is advisable is another story.

Comment: please see my response below; those queries should work fine for you

Comment: @Abhay: I see them. No need to point them out in a comment too ;) I'll try out your solutions tomorrow when I go back to work. Your solution does sound more promising if your right about datediff returning days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, FROM_UNIXTIME(`dob`), FROM_UNIXTIME(`point_in_time`)), 
    'y ',
    MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, FROM_UNIXTIME(`dob`), FROM_UNIXTIME(`point_in_time`)), 12),
    'm'
) `age`
...
...
```

Another one might be:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    FLOOR((`point_in_time` - `dob`) / 31536000),
    'y ',
    FLOOR(MOD((`point_in_time` - `dob`) / 31536000 * 12, 12)),
    'm'
) `age`
...
...
```

Hope this helps?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONCAT(    
  YEAR(DATE_ADD('2000-01-01',INTERVAL (DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(tpit), FROM_UNIXTIME(dob))) DAY))-2000, 'y ',
  MONTH(DATE_ADD('2000-01-01',INTERVAL (DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(tpit), FROM_UNIXTIME(dob))) DAY)), 'm'
  ) as output 
FROM ..... WHERE .....
```

Comment: I think this might not give the right results because 1. DATEDIFF does date1 - date2, so the order should be tpit, dob; 2. YEAR() and MONTH() accept date arguments but DATEDIFF() returns the difference in number of days

Comment: Abhay's right. This definitely doesn't work. `FROM_UNIXTIME` needs an underscore, you've got the order of the dates mixed, and `DATEDIFF` returns days so you can't grab the year part.

Comment: @Mask, Abhay, Fixed the query to translate the days to dates.